# HTTP protocol verification tooling

Tags: http, testing

Is there a good tool that can be used to verify the HTTP responses from a web server are valid as per the various HTTP RFCs?

Context is - we have a bunch of spring-boot microservices deployed on k8s that use istio. Recently we upgraded istio, which caused all our APIs to die with a rather cryptic http 503 and this body:

`upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination`

[The issue was triggered by this change in envoy](https://discuss.istio.io/t/unsupported-transfer-encoding-error-in-istio-proxy/6021) that was enforcing http protocol violations.  The root cause was actually one of our microservices was returning 2 `Transfer-Encoding` headers (it was calling an upstream service using feign and simply returning the upstream response as is, which would have been fine except that feign translates all headers into lower case, so we end up with 2 TE headers).

In order to trap errors like this, I'm looking for a library / tool / whatever that can make a HTTP request and assert the response is valid as per the HTTP RFCs, however I can't seem to find anything that is tailored to making assertions (rather than doing something like envoy, which is just blowing up when it finds something that is invalid)

Comment: Did you see Jmeter Assertion features ? https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion

Comment: What's your issue with Envoy? It makes sense to me what your test environment is similar enough to your production environment, exactly to catch errors like this. Even if you use a HTTP linter/protocol tester there's no guarantee that they are going to catch the exact same things Envoy does.

Comment: The issue isn't with envoy, it's just that it's not specifically for asserting correctness as per the protocol - It just happens to do that when performing the proxy function. I'm looking for something that can make a request, get the response and provide a report saying "here's all the stuff that's wrong" and even better would be something that can do that over different contexts - http1.0, http1.1, keep-alives, http2 maybe quic